# Git - amending an historical commit

Tags: git, github, version-control

So you're working along like a good little developer: you commit one set of changes, let's call it `foundation`. Then you finish up the next segment and commit, lets call it `framework`. You're about to move onto the next step of `cleanup` when you realize: Oh No! I forgot to add an important change to my `foundation` commit! (let's call it `patch`)

But not to fear. Git allows us to *edit history**. No one will ever see our mistakes...

*to review this is what our commit history looks like*

```
patch
|
framework
|
foundation
|
everything that came before
...
```

---

As far as I know there are two basic ways we could go about this. First method, commit the changes of `patch` and then use `git rebase -i` to change the order of commits and squash/fixup `patch` into `foundation`. Second method, stash the changes in `patch` then using `git rebase -i` edit the `foundation` commit using `git commit --amend`. That is:

### First method

`git commit -am 'patch'`

`git rebase -i`

```
# Originally
# pick foundation
# pick framework
# pick patch

# Now 
pick foundation
fixup patch
pick framework
```

### Second method

`git stash`

`git rebase -i`

```
# Originally
# pick foundation
# pick framework

# Now 
edit foundation
pick framework
```

`git stash apply`

`git commit --amend`

`git rebase --continue`

---

At the end of both of these methods, we will have the commit history of

```
framework
|
foundation+patch
|
everything that came before
...
```

---

## So my question is

Should we prefer one process over another? And if so why? What benefits/risks are involved with one or the other?

---

***Disclaimer:** Time travel is dangerous. Editing your history could *destroy* your repo, especially if it has been shared with multiple people. Use this power wisely...

Comment: Why the downvote on the question? What do you think I could do to make this a better question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no reason to prefer either of those two methods.

Most commonly, especially for tricky cases, I use a third method! :-)

The key step is to rename the current experiment branch, and create a new experiment branch:

```
git branch -m experiment experiment.0  # increment number over time
git checkout -b experiment  # and add an upstream if desired
```

Now you can commit the patch, including using `git commit --fixup`, and then run an interactive rebase (perhaps with `--autosquash`) and re-work the foundation and framework.

Each "abandoned" previous attempt thus remains as a visible, numbered previous attempt.  When all is good, I delete the old ones with `git branch -D` and they're now really-abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between the two method you listed should be whether use `fixup` or `edit`  for `git rebase -i` command.

Both of the two method are ok. But the **second method** can make the commit history more clearly, especially if you co-work with others for the same repo/branch, squash commits is not recommended. While if you want the history to be short, you can squash as the first method.

And for the second method, you can also commit `patch`  first and then rewrite the commit `foundation`:

```
git commit -am 'patch'
git rebase -i
```

In rebase interactive window, change it as:

```
edit foundation
pick framework
pick patch
```